# ECONNREFUSED hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

We have been using hapijs for a while and suddenly started getting this problem

```
hapi, {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","domainEmitter":{"domain":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"members":[]},"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10},"domain":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"members":[]},"domainThrown":false}
Debug: hapi, internal, implementation, error 
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

I'm not sure as to why I'm getting this error. I tried with different versions of node but no success. Is anybody else having this issue?

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you're listening on a `port` that is not available?

Answer (score 0):

The port the server is listening on is not available. This could be either that it is in use by another process, or you are trying to listen to a port the current user isn't authorized to listen on.

For instance, Port 80 is a privileged port and will not be possible to listen on, if you are running as a normal user. You can do

`authbind --deep node app.js`

That won't require root.